# Cambiar texto por defecto de un div - al seleccionar opción grupo radio

Tags: javascript

Tengo un grupo radio con una función para mostrar el texto del Valor. Puse para que por defecto tenga una opción seleccionada. Quiero que el texto de esa opción aparezca también por defecto, sin embargo no pude.

Pensé que podría ese mismo texto estar escrito, aparte del texto del `input`,  y que cambie al seleccionarse por el de la opción seleccionada.

Este es el código:

```js
$(function() {
  var $radBtn = $("#odontologia");
  $radBtn.click(function() {
    var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked');
    $("#forro").text('')
      .append($radChecked.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ef-example-1-rating" id="odontologia">
               <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello5" >
           <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
               <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello4">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello3">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello2">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello1" checked="yes">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <br />
    <p id="forro" style="color:red;"></p>
    </span>
```

Comment: He editado tu pregunta. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es que deje por defecto el texto quemado en la etiqueta `p`, tal como muestro en el siguiente código:

```js
$(function() {
  var $radBtn = $("#odontologia");
  $radBtn.click(function() {
    var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked');
    $("#forro").text('')
      .append($radChecked.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ef-example-1-rating" id="odontologia">
               <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello5" >
           <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
               <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello4">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello3">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello2">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello1" checked="yes">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <br />
    <p id="forro" style="color:red;">Hello1</p>
    </span>
```

Otra opción es modificar el código `onclick` en una función separada y que, al cargar la página, llame a esta función.

Answer (score 0):

Hola debes agregar esto en tu jquery:

```
$("#forro").text('')
        .append($('input:radio[name=ef-example-1-rating-input-1]:checked').val());
```

```js
$(function() {

  $("#forro").text('')
            .append($('input:radio[name=ef-example-1-rating-input-1]:checked').val());

    var $radBtn = $("#odontologia");
    $radBtn.click(function() {
        var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked');
        $("#forro").text('')
            .append($radChecked.val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ef-example-1-rating" id="odontologia">
           <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello5" >
       <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
           <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello4">
<label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
<input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello3">
<label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
<input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello2">
<label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
<input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello1" checked="yes">
<label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
<br />
<p id="forro" style="color:red;"></p>
</span>
```

Comment: Hola, resuelto . Muchas gracias

Comment: Que bueno, no olvides votar por la respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Haces la búsqueda del `:radio:checked` al inicio e inicias el valor del texto a `#forro`.

Además podes colgarte del evento change de cada radio y si está checked le aplicas el valor de ese radio al texto de `#forro` al cual para no repetir y buscar cada vez lo pones en una variable.

```js
$(function() {
  var $radBtn = $("#odontologia");
  var $forro = $("#forro");

  // valor inicial el que esté checked
  $forro.text($radBtn.find(':radio:checked').val());

  // cuando cambia algun radio usar el valor del mismo si es que está checked
  $radBtn.find(':radio').on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
      $forro.text($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ef-example-1-rating" id="odontologia">
               <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello5" >
           <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
               <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello4">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello3">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello2">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello1" checked="yes">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <br />
    <p id="forro" style="color:red;">ASDFASDFASDFA</p>
    </span>
```